# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I get the index out of range exception when compiling my grid view to display a set of orders.

It doesn't happen when I add a new row but it does occur when I try to delete or update a row.

Any help is much appreciated.

The designer is:

```
<asp:GridView   ID="GridView1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        DataKeyNames="" 
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
                        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
                        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
                        ShowFooter="True" 
                        OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="editButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add New"></asp:Button>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewOrderID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Taken by">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderTaker" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderTaker") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewOrderTaker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderTaker") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order By">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderBy") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewOrderBy" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderBy") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lens Material">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaterial" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Material") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewMaterial" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Material") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tint">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTint" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Tint") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewTint" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Tint") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BCOR">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBCOR" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BCOR") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewBCOR" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BCOR") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Power">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPower" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Power") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPower" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Power") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Diameter">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDiameter" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Diameter") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDiameter" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelDiameter" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Diameter") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Design">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesign" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Design") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDesign" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Design") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewNotes" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />
            </Columns>             
        </asp:GridView>
```

The code-behind is:

```
public class LensOrdersCls
{

    private string cnstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PatientConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    private string sql;

    public LensOrdersCls()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void Insert(int OrderID, string Date, string OrderTaker, string OrderBy, string Material, string Tint, string BCOR, string Power, string Diameter, string Design, string Notes)
    {
        string sql = "Insert Into LensOrders (OrderID, Date, OrderTaker, OrderBy, Material, Tint, BCOR, Power, Diameter, Design, Notes) Values ('" + OrderID
            + "' , '" + Date + "', '" + OrderTaker + "', '" + OrderBy + "', '" + Material + "' , '" + Tint + "' , '" + BCOR + "' , '" + Power + "', '" + Diameter + "', '" + Design + "', '" + Notes + "')";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }

    public DataTable Fetch()
    {
        string sql = "Select * From LensOrders";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnstr);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }



    public void Update(int OrderID, string Date, string OrderTaker, string OrderBy, string Material, string Tint, string BCOR, string Power, string Diameter, string Design, string Notes)
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE LensOrders SET OrderID='" + OrderID + "', Date = '" + Date
            + "', OrderTaker='" + OrderTaker + "', OrderBy = '" + OrderBy + "' Material=" + Material + "' Tint= '" + Tint + "' BCOR= '" + BCOR + "' Power '" + Power + "' Diameter= '" + Diameter + "' Design= '" + Design + "' Notes= '" + Notes;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }

    public void Delete(int OrderID)
    {
        string sql = "Delete LensOrders Where OrderID=" + OrderID;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }

}
```

The page code-behind is:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    LensOrdersCls LensOrder = new LensOrdersCls();

    private void FillOrdersInGrid()
    {
        DataTable dtOrder = LensOrder.Fetch();

        if (dtOrder.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dtOrder;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            dtOrder.Rows.Add(dtOrder.NewRow());
            GridView1.DataSource = dtOrder;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            int TotalColumns = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = TotalColumns;
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Record Found";
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            FillOrdersInGrid();
            test.Text = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count.ToString();
        }
    }


    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
        {
            TextBox txtNewOrderID =     (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewOrderID");
            TextBox txtNewDate =        (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewDate");
            TextBox txtNewOrderTaker =  (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewOrderTaker");
            TextBox txtNewOrderBy =     (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewOrderBy");
            TextBox txtNewMaterial =    (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewMaterial");
            TextBox txtNewTint =        (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewTint");
            TextBox txtNewBCOR =        (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewBCOR");
            TextBox txtNewPower =       (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewPower");
            TextBox txtNewDiameter =    (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewDiameter");
            TextBox txtNewDesign =      (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewDesign");
            TextBox txtNewNotes =       (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewNotes");

            LensOrder.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(txtNewOrderID.Text), 
                             txtNewDate.Text,
                             txtNewOrderTaker.Text, 
                             txtNewOrderBy.Text,
                             txtNewMaterial.Text,
                             txtNewTint.Text,
                             txtNewBCOR.Text,
                             txtNewPower.Text,
                             txtNewDiameter.Text,
                             txtNewDesign.Text,
                             txtNewNotes.Text);

            FillOrdersInGrid();
        }
    }

    // Row Editing
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        FillOrdersInGrid();
    }

    // Row Cancel editing
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        FillOrdersInGrid();
    }

    //Row updating
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtOrderID =    (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtOrderID");
        TextBox txtDate =       (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDate");
        TextBox txtOrderTaker = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtOrderTaker");
        TextBox txtOrderBy =    (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtNewOrderBy");
        TextBox txtMaterial =   (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMaterial");
        TextBox txtTint =       (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTint");
        TextBox txtBCOR =       (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBCOR");
        TextBox txtPower =      (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPower");
        TextBox txtDiameter =   (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDiameter");
        TextBox txtDesign =     (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDesign");
        TextBox txtNotes =      (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtNotes");

        LensOrder.Update(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString()),
                        txtDate.Text,
                        txtOrderTaker.Text,
                        txtOrderBy.Text,
                        txtMaterial.Text,
                        txtTint.Text,
                        txtBCOR.Text,
                        txtPower.Text,
                        txtDiameter.Text,
                        txtDesign.Text,
                        txtNotes.Text);

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        FillOrdersInGrid();
    }

    //Deleting row

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        LensOrder.Delete(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString())); 
        FillOrdersInGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the name of the data key for the Grid, but your delete method references DataKeys[e.RowIndex]. I think that's where the exception gets thrown.

Set DataKeyNames="OrderId" in your mark-up.

Comment: Hi cdonner, 
Thanks that is certainly something I have over looked but still the problem persists.