# Index was out of range, must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Can someone please tell me whats going on?

I'm trying to make a random question appear in `Label1` when `Button1` is pressed. I only want each question to appear once.

```
Dim Qtn(4) As String
Private Sub LoadQs()
    Qtn(0) = "What is 1 + 10?"
    Qtn(1) = "What is 1 + 11?"
    Qtn(2) = "What is 1 + 12?"
    Qtn(3) = "What is 1 + 13?"
    Qtn(4) = "What is 1 + 14?"
End Sub
Private Sub RndQtn()
    Dim list As New ArrayList
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        'Add the numbers to the collection.
        list.Add(i)
    Next i
    Dim randomValue As New Random
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim item As Object
    'Display the items in random order.
    While list.Count > 0
        'Choose a random index.
        index = randomValue.Next(0, Qtn.Length)
        'Get the item at that index.
        item = list(index)
        'Remove the item so that it cannot be chosen again.
        list.RemoveAt(index)
        'Display the item.
        Label1.Text = Qtn(item)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Take a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306742/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-colle) too. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know VB, but in this code

```
    index = randomValue.Next(0, Qtn.Length)
    'Get the item at that index.
    item = list(index)
    'Remove the item so that it cannot be chosen again.
    list.RemoveAt(index)
```

you're generating an index based on the length of `Qtn`, but using it to index into `list`, which is a different variable. And because you do `list.RemoveAt(index)`, `list` keeps shrinking, but `Qtn.Length` stays the same. There's a good chance that `randomValue.Next(0, Qtn.Length)` will produce out-of-bounds values when `list` goes down to 2 or 1 elements.

Comment: You're correct. The fix is simply doing `randomValue.Next(0, list.Length)` instead, as you point out.